# Treelist get rid of roots. Just leafs should be shown

Tags: java, javafx, root, treelist

I am trying to get rid of the roots (Bucky and Megan). If I click the button, it doesn't work. Could anyone help me pls?

The leafs (Michael, YouTube, Video, Lipstick, Glitter) should not disappear.

I have no idea why it doesn't work.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
    Stage window;
    TreeView<String> tree;


    public static void main (String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("javaFX TreeView");


        TreeItem<String> root, bucky, megan;

        //Root
        root = new TreeItem<String>();
        root.setExpanded(true);


        //Bucky
        bucky = makeBranch ("Bucky", root);
        makeBranch ("Michael", bucky);
        makeBranch ("YouTube", bucky);
        makeBranch ("Video", bucky);


        //Megan
        megan = makeBranch ("Megan", root);
        makeBranch ("Lipstick", megan);
        makeBranch ("Glitter", megan);

        //Create tree
        tree = new TreeView<String>(root);
        tree.setShowRoot(false);

        //Layout
        final StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setText("Knopf");
        layout.getChildren().add(tree);
        layout.getChildren().add(button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();

        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                tree.setShowRoot(false);
            }
        });
    }
    //Create branches
    public TreeItem<String> makeBranch(String title, TreeItem<String> parent){
        TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<String>(title);
        item.setExpanded(true);
        parent.getChildren().add(item);
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't copy random text into your question.

Comment: Please describe what it is supposed to do exactly (sample input, sample output, etc) and what your code is currently producing.

Comment: not supported ... anyway, why? If you want a plain list, use a list. If you want a subtree (or collection of subtrees) re-build the hierarchy ..